# iptables NAT on Debian openvz

Tags: debian, iptables, nat, openvz

So i want to create a nat rule for an openVPN server.
After getting trouble with the TAP/TUN Devices, it's finally working i think.
Now i have to make a nat rule like so :

```
>iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.0.0/24 -o venet0:1 -j MASQUERADE   
iptables v1.4.14: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

But it doesn't work. I searched a lot and found another command

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -j DNAT  --to-destination 5.135.###.###
```

This command does the same result as the previous one.
Don't know what to do.
I ask the host to enable nat but he tell me that i have to do it on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iptables MASQUERADE is roughly the same as source nat (SNAT), as the source IP address is translated or masqueraded.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.0.0/24 -o venet0:1 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4
```

1.2.3.4 is your outgoing IP address - I guess 5.135.###.### in your case.